# How enable fingerprint in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, fingerprint-reader

I'm using ubuntu version 22.04 and dual booting windows 11. In my windows operating system, I can log in with a fingerprint. There is no setting displayed on the setting -> users page(I have attached a screenshot here).
[image]

And my laptop details are here.

[image]

And my machine also recognised the fingerprint sensors.
[image]

And according to these [article](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/sp3iky/how_to_enable_fingerprint_login_in_ubuntu_on_dell/) I tried to install drivers. but I got these errors.

```
(base) kasun@kasun:~$ wget http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/pool/public/libf/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix_0.0.4-0ubuntu1somerville1_amd64.deb
--2022-07-05 13:52:34--  http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/pool/public/libf/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix_0.0.4-0ubuntu1somerville1_amd64.deb
Resolving dell.archive.canonical.com (dell.archive.canonical.com)... 185.125.189.10
Connecting to dell.archive.canonical.com (dell.archive.canonical.com)|185.125.189.10|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 548108 (535K) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘libfprint-2-tod1-goodix_0.0.4-0ubuntu1somerville1_amd64.deb.1’

libfprint-2-tod1-go 100%[===================>] 535.26K   158KB/s    in 3.4s    

2022-07-05 13:52:38 (158 KB/s) - ‘libfprint-2-tod1-goodix_0.0.4-0ubuntu1somerville1_amd64.deb.1’ saved [548108/548108]

(base) kasun@kasun:~$ sudo dpkg -i libfprint-2-tod1-goodix_0.0.4-0ubuntu1somerville1_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 265018 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libfprint-2-tod1-goodix_0.0.4-0ubuntu1somerville1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfprint-2-tod1-goodix (0.0.4-0ubuntu1somerville1) over (0.0.4-0ubuntu1somerville1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libfprint-2-tod1-goodix:
 libfprint-2-tod1-goodix depends on libfprint-2-tod1 (>= 1.90.1); however:
  Package libfprint-2-tod1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libfprint-2-tod1-goodix (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libfprint-2-tod1-goodix
```

Comment: did you install `libfprint-2-tod1`?

Comment: Yes. @Esther, I have installed that. nut nothing happem

Comment: what do you mean by "nothing"? it says you're missing that as a dependency, what output does it give once you installed the dependency?

Comment: @Esther, I have installed that package. It successfully installed but in setting -> users page nothing changed

Comment: yes, you installed the dependency. Now install the package you were trying to install in this question, did you do that?